# Having an error of setting array element with a sequence in a two dimensional vector

Tags: python, matrix, vector, sequence

I want to calculate a two dimensional vector with two for loops, each calculating some parameters.
My inputs are:

```
Temp= array([ 25.,  30.,  50.,  25.,  25.,  25.])
Ir= array([ 1000.,  500.,  1000.,  100.,  200.,  1000.])
```

In the first loop, I calculate the some vectors and in the inner loop, I want to calculate a matrix `I(x,t)` with the size of `len(V)*N`

Problem: I receive the following error for the inner loop (`I(x,t)`):

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

What is my mistake and how can I fix it.

```
from math import *
from pylab import *
from numpy import *

Area=243.36
N=6
V = arange(0,0.7,0.01)
Jsc_cell = 0.03785
Isc_cell = Jsc_cell * Area
n1=1.0
J01 = 6.2e-13
Is1 = J01 * Area
n2= 2.0
J02 = 7.3e-9
Is2= J02 * Area
T_co = 0.0005
Rs = 2.7487398e-3
Rsh = 410913.8725
k = 1.38e-23
q = 1.6e-19
Eg=1.11
Tmeas= 273+25.0

Iph=zeros(N)
I0=zeros(N)
I02=zeros(N)
Vt=zeros(N)
I=zeros((len(V),N))
T=zeros(N)

for t in range(0,6):
    T[t] = Temp[t]+273.0
    Vt[t]=(k*T[t])/q
    I0[t]=Is1*((T[t]/Tmeas)**(3/n1))*exp(Eg*((T[t]/Tmeas)-1)/(n1*Vt[t]));
    I02[t]=Is2*((T[t]/Tmeas)**(3/n2))*exp(Eg*((T[t]/Tmeas)-1)/(n2*Vt[t]));
    Iph[t] = Isc_cell*(Ir[t]/1000.0)*(1+(T_co*(Temp[t]-25)));

    for x in range(len(V)):
        I[x,t] = Iph[t] - I0[t]*(exp((V[x]+I[t]*Rs)/(n1*Vt[t]))-1)-I02[t]*(exp((V[x]+I[t]*Rs)/(n2*Vt[t]))-1)-((V[x]+I[t]*Rs)/Rsh);
        x=x+1

    t=t+1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to assign a 1x2 array (computed from `I[t]`) to a 1x1 element `I[x,t]`.

```
I[x,t] = Iph[t] - I0[t]*(exp((V[x]+I[t]*Rs)/(n1*Vt[t]))-1)-I02[t]*(exp((V[x]+I[t]*Rs)/(n2*Vt[t]))-1)-((V[x]+I[t]*Rs)/Rsh);
~~~~~~                             ~~~~                                      ~~~~                           ~~~~
```

That doesn't work. What is supposed to happen with the second element?

---

By the way: You probably don't want to increment the loop counters `x` and `t` manually.

Comment: Thanks for the hint again. I replace it with `I(x,t)` and now it works.
sorry that I cannot vote up for you since I have not enough reputations. Accept my thanks in comment.